# How does this OWL conversion works?

Tags: rdf, owl

The example from https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-overview/:

```
 @prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
 @prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

 <http://example.org/alice#me> a foaf:Person .
 <http://example.org/alice#me> foaf:name "Alice" .
 <http://example.org/alice#me> foaf:mbox <mailto:alice@example.org> .
 <http://example.org/alice#me> foaf:knows <http://example.org/bob#me> .
 <http://example.org/bob#me> foaf:knows <http://example.org/alice#me> .
 <http://example.org/bob#me> foaf:name "Bob" .
 <http://example.org/alice#me> foaf:knows <http://example.org/charlie#me> .
 <http://example.org/charlie#me> foaf:knows <http://example.org/alice#me> .
 <http://example.org/charlie#me> foaf:name "Charlie" .
 <http://example.org/alice#me> foaf:knows <http://example.org/snoopy> .
 <http://example.org/snoopy> foaf:name "Snoopy"@en .
```

I loaded this turtle ontology into Protege and them saved as RDF/XML format, it is converted this form:

```
<!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Annotation properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->
    <!-- http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows -->
    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows"/>
    <!-- http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/mbox -->
    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/mbox"/>
    <!-- http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name -->
    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name"/>

    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->
    <!-- http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person -->
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"/>

    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    <!-- http://example.org/alice#me -->
    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://example.org/alice#me">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"/>
        <foaf:knows rdf:resource="http://example.org/snoopy"/>
        <foaf:knows rdf:resource="http://example.org/bob#me"/>
        <foaf:knows rdf:resource="http://example.org/charlie#me"/>
        <foaf:mbox rdf:resource="mailto:alice@example.org"/>
        <foaf:name>Alice</foaf:name>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Annotations
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/snoopy">
        <foaf:name xml:lang="en">Snoopy</foaf:name>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/bob#me">
        <foaf:knows rdf:resource="http://example.org/alice#me"/>
        <foaf:name>Bob</foaf:name>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/charlie#me">
        <foaf:name>Charlie</foaf:name>
        <foaf:knows rdf:resource="http://example.org/alice#me"/>
    </rdf:Description>
```

Why do "name, mbox and knows" become annotation properties? Shouldn't they be Object Properties? Also, why does only "Alice" become NamedIndividuals? Shouldn't "Bob", "Snoopy" and "Charlie" be the same?

Comment: OWL 2 entities have to be typed, otherwise the OWL parser of Protege resp. OWL API can't determine the type the property. What you loaded is just an RDF document, Protege needs as I said, a proper OWL 2 ontology.

Comment: Why is "foaf:name" Annotation Property, not Object Property?

Comment: Because foaf:name has no declaration as object property in this ontology

Comment: Alice is the only individual explicitly declared with a type. However individuals do not need a declaration, so this is not an issue.

Comment: ＠Ignazio, if foaf:name is not a object property, then it must be a data property? Why does it automatically become an annotation property? Annotation is for informational purpose only.

Comment: What? Have you read my initial comment?! I told you that entity types have to be declared in OWL. And your statement *"must be a data property"* is **not** true. In OWL there are 3 types of properties, who decides what? Annotations can also be string values, thus, how can a parser distinguish between data property and annotation property? Anyways, one more time: **entity types have to be declared in OWL** - nothing more to discuss here. Read the W3C specs

Comment: ＠AKSW, what about "http://example.org/alice#me"? why is there a 'me' in this declaration?